# including external jsp file inside velocity template

Tags: file, jsp, velocity, inclusion

velocity templates works fine in developing web pages. But i would also like to include certain jsp pages inside my velocity template to include certain functionalities. But when i try, #include("xyz.jsp") it simply pastes the file in my template rather than binding it..kindly help me out..

Answer (score 0):

You need to being using VelocityTools' [ImportTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/view/ImportTool.html).